# Pillow cannot be installed via pip

Tags: python, linux, jpeg, python-imaging-library, libjpeg

When I try to run pip install pillow, I get:

```
ValueError: --enable-jpeg requested but jpeg not found, aborting.
```

I installed lib-jpeg (via brew install libjpeg and brew install jpeg), and I also installed pillow (via brew install pillow) in my virtual environment. But, pip install pillow still does not work, and when I try to run my code, which uses the imread() function, imread() is not recognized (which means that pillow is not installed?).

I do not have root access (so I cannot use sudo apt-get) I am ssh'd into an Odyssey computer using the CentOS 6.5 version of the Linux. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes when pip fails, I have better luck with `easy_install`

Comment: I tried easy_install pillow but encounter the same issue with libjpeg missing. easy_install libjpeg doesn't work either. Any tips?

Comment: I just had this same problem today. I'm not at a computer, but when I am I'll post the package I installed to fix this. Unfortunately for you though, you would need root access to install it. Sorry.

Comment: if you can install virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper, you don't need root to pip

Comment: I am using a virtual environment @joelgoldstick but even though I'm installed pillow and libjpeg via brew, I still get the jpeg error. Any suggestions?

Comment: when in your virtualenv you should be able to do pip without sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out.

I have to install anaconda via:

wget http://09c8d0b2229f813c1b93-c95ac804525aac4b6dba79b00b39d1d3.r79.cf1.rackcdn.com/Anaconda-2.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

and pillow will be one of the modules installed!